# Jmockit activate and deactivate MockUp object inside the same methode

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, jmockit

I am writing a test case for a scenario at which the customer can upload contents into the DB. in this test case I assumed the contents are missing, so `RuntimeException(PAYLOAD_NOT_FOUND)` will be thrown and in the `catch` block I will construct dummy content and continue another execution path.

To simulate missing contents I am mocking the getContent getter

```
        new MockUp<CustomerContentDto>() {
            @Mock
            public String getContent() {
                throw new RuntimeException(PAYLOAD_NOT_FOUND);
            }
        };
```

So far so good, the problem that I need to call `public String getContent()` after constructing the dummy contents, but every time I call this method the mock will throw `new RuntimeException(PAYLOAD_NOT_FOUND);`
Is there is any way to deactivate that mock after certain execution point?

```
 @Test
    public void uploadContent_PayloadMissing_uploadError() throws DaoException, URISyntaxException, IOException,MessageTaskException {

    final String sameAccounts = "some info...";

    new MockUp<CustomerContentDto>() {
        @Mock
        public String getContent() {
            throw new RuntimeException(PAYLOAD_NOT_FOUND);
        }
    };

    // i need to mock getContent() befor this call
    objectUnderTest.handleMessage(111,sxpConnection);

    new Verifications() {{
        CustomerContentDto customerContentDto;
        iCustomerContentDao.setApproved(anyLong, anyString, null);
        minTimes = 1;
        maxTimes = 1;
        iCustomerContentDao.uploadContent(customerContentDto = withCapture());
        maxTimes = 1;

        // i need to deactivate the mock getContent() befor this call
        Assert.assertEquals(customerContentDto.getContent(), "111\n\n\"Content is missing a Payload tag\"");
    }};
}
```

Comment: I can only offer to say: in Mockito, you can create a fluent chain call, like `when(foo.bar).thenThrow(new Whatever()).thenReturn()` .

Comment: I'm not even sure if can do that. Once you mock the method, you have it mocked forever (at least, as far as I know). Either way, you're doing a weird test, if you mock a method to give out an exception, why are you using it again for a verification? Maybe partial mocking could help you but I doubt it as it mocks methods http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Mocking.html#partial

Comment: You can, of course, record a sequence of results for an expectation with the JMockit *mocking* API. This test has *lots* of problems, however... For starters, why use a `MockUp` in the first place? Or why mock a DTO?